# How to index intermediate dimension with an index tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

How can I index a tensor `t` with n dimensions with an `index` tensor of m < n dimensions, such that the last dimensions of `t` are preserved? The `index` tensor is shaped equal to tensor `t` for all dimensions before dimension m. Or in other terms, I want to index intermediate dimensions of a tensor, while keeping all the following dimensions of the selected indices preserved.

For example, lets say we have the two tensors:

```
t = torch.randn([3, 5, 2]) * 10
index = torch.tensor([[1, 3],[0,4],[3,2]]).long()
```

with t:

```
tensor([[[ 15.2165,  -7.9702],
         [  0.6646,   5.2844],
         [-22.0657,  -5.9876],
         [ -9.7319,  11.7384],
         [  4.3985,  -6.7058]],

        [[-15.6854, -11.9362],
         [ 11.3054,   3.3068],
         [ -4.7756,  -7.4524],
         [  5.0977, -17.3831],
         [  3.9152, -11.5047]],

        [[ -5.4265, -22.6456],
         [  1.6639,  10.1483],
         [ 13.2129,   3.7850],
         [  3.8543,  -4.3496],
         [ -8.7577, -12.9722]]])
```

Then the output I would like to have would have shape `(3, 2, 2)` and be:

```
tensor([[[  0.6646,   5.2844],
         [ -9.7319,  11.7384]],
        [[-15.6854, -11.9362],
         [  3.9152, -11.5047]],
        [[  3.8543,  -4.3496],
         [ 13.2129,   3.7850]]])
```

Another example would be that I have a tensor `t` of shape `(40, 10, 6, 2)` and an index tensor of shape `(40, 10, 3)`. This should query dimension 3 of tensor `t` and the expected output shape would be `(40, 10, 3, 2)`.

How can I achieve this in a generic way, without using loops?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can do something like this:

```py
t[torch.arange(t.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1), index, ...]
```

Full code:

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[[ 15.2165,  -7.9702],
                   [  0.6646,   5.2844],
                   [-22.0657,  -5.9876],
                   [ -9.7319,  11.7384],
                   [  4.3985,  -6.7058]],
                  [[-15.6854, -11.9362],
                   [ 11.3054,   3.3068],
                   [ -4.7756,  -7.4524],
                   [  5.0977, -17.3831],
                   [  3.9152, -11.5047]],
                  [[ -5.4265, -22.6456],
                   [  1.6639,  10.1483],
                   [ 13.2129,   3.7850],
                   [  3.8543,  -4.3496],
                   [ -8.7577, -12.9722]]])

index = torch.tensor([[1, 3],[0,4],[3,2]]).long()

output = t[torch.arange(t.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1), index, ...]

# tensor([[[  0.6646,   5.2844],
#          [ -9.7319,  11.7384]],
# 
#         [[-15.6854, -11.9362],
#          [  3.9152, -11.5047]],
# 
#         [[  3.8543,  -4.3496],
#          [ 13.2129,   3.7850]]])
```

Comment: But this solution is not generic, right? What if my t as 5 dimensions and my index 3, or 4?

Comment: @Chris then your index is ill-defined... update your question with another example, please. Make sure your index has a definition. For instance, I had to introduce an assumption in my answer because it is not clear how your index is supposed to be used, except if you look at the output, then one notices that the index is incomplete.

Comment: My question was generic, that is why I used n and m for dimensions. The example is of course concrete. You have n dimensions and want to query that tensor in an intermediate dimension m (which is smaller than n). The index tensor is defined up to dimension m and all dimensions before m are equal to the target tensor. I may add that information, I thought its obvious.

Comment: I extended my description, hope this makes what I mean clearer!

Comment: @Chris your index continues to be ill-defined. For instance, how output[i,j,k] is defined for m=3 and n=2? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Chris if you prefer, instead of using notation, you can show how would you do it using a for loop. Both ways require a proper definition for the index.